# Is anyone able to connect to MongoDB using the new mongodb .net 2.0 client?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I installed MongoDB.Driver 2.0 from nuget published 4/2/2015.  I also installed MondgoDB via chocolatey version 2.4.7.  I created a test app in VS2013, as follows:

```
var client = new MongoClient();
var database = client.GetDatabase("foo");
var foo = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("bar");
```

From what I have read in the docs, this should be sufficient to connect to the server and create the database.  When I check the mongodb via robomongo, I dont see that the database "foo" has been created.

I tried running mongodb via windows server and via command line (admin mode), with no results.  I have disabled my firewall just in case that was an issue; still nothing.  I have to say that as my first foray into MongoDB I would have expected this to just work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... and create the database

there is no such operation in mongodb, databases are created when you attempt to insert data into one

> What am I missing?

You're not asking the driver to actually *do* anything. All operations are lazy. To have the driver connect and insert a document, thereby creating both the database and the collection, do something like this:

```
var foo = database.GetCollection<Customer>("customer");
foo.InsertOneAsync(new Customer { Name = "John Doe" }).Wait();
```

where `Customer` is a class, e.g.

```
public class Customer { 
  public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, you can also work with `BsonDocuments`, but that seems unnecessarily cumbersome.

Comment: Thank you mnemosyn!!  Looks like I stopped short of the finish line.